No se ejecuta segundo UPDATE en store procedure con los mismos parametros
quisiera pedir ayuda con algo que no puedo resolver o hacer funcionar, me estoy volviendo loco intentando actualizar dos tablas diferentes desde un store procedure con dos simples variables.
Tengo dos tablas una de usuarios y otra de equipos, la tabla Users tiene el campo Idinventory (saber que equipo tiene asignado) y la tabla Inventory tiene el campo UserId (saber que usuario tiene asigando el equipo). Hago hambos updates con un store que recibe dos parametros desde un boton de asp.net
Store Procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE [intranet].[sp_AssignMachine]

  @UserId INT,
  @IdInventory INT
  AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE tbl_Users
    SET IdInventory = @IdInventory
    WHERE UserId = @UserId
    
    UPDATE tbl_ITInventory
    SET MStatus = 'Asignado', UserId = @UserId
    WHERE IdInventory = @IdInventory

  END
  GO

Codigo de C#
protected void btnAssigment_Command(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_AssignMachine", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdInventory", ddlST.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", ddlUserId.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Equipo asignado.');", true);
        
    }
}

}


¿Por qué crees que no se ejecuta el segundo update? Todo indica que sí lo hará, pero es probable que no tenga los valores que crees. Podrías validarlo de múltiples maneras, ya sea con Profiler, Extended Events o solo ejecutando el Procedimiento Almacenado directamente y consultar las tablas.

Hola, según veo tu store procedure debería de funcionar correctamente, ya revisaste si los parametros que estás enviando desde C# se encuentran con los valores que necesitas? o sino, ya has revisado si hay algún trigger que esté cancelando la actualización de la segunda tabla?

y ademas de todo algo me dice que tus tablas estan muy mal.. si la tabla A referencia a la B, y la B a la A, eso esta claramente mal...

El segundo UPDATE puede que no se ejecuta si hay una relación circular o un trigger que interfiera. Mira los valores de los parámetros y si existen triggers que afecten la segunda tabla. Es posible un trigger que podría estar causando el problema

Que el segundo UPDATE puede no ejecutarse debido a una de estas razones:

Valores incorrectos en los parámetros: Verifica que @UserId y @IdInventory tengan los valores esperados en el procedimiento almacenado
Triggers: Revisa si hay algún trigger en las tablas que esté interfiriendo o revirtiendo la actualización
Relación circular: Si las tablas se referencian mutuamente, reconsidera el diseño de la base de datos

Debuggea el procedimiento almacenado directamente y revisa si hay algún trigger activo, entonces vas a ver que falla.

Gracias a todos por sus comentarios y sugerencias, revise los valores enviados y la respuesta del Store, al final despues de varias pruebas encontre que al cargar los datos del DropDownList mi evento load no tenia declarado el PostBack , al declararlo ya funciono correctamente
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

